# Facebook login into native mode from iOS6

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, ios6

my new issue(!!) 
My app continous to ask me permission for publish on Facebook if I set my account into native mode [ios6] (from Settings > Facebook) and not makes the login!!!
Instead if I don't set native login, my app goes to my Facebook's app for ask permissions and all works fine....

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I've found myself the answer!!!
I need to configure better my app on Facebook. I need to set the Bundle ID into "Native app" setting!!!

Now into General Settings of IOS I can see my (xCode) app!

Good.... thanks however!!!